# How write XSL stylesheet to add attribute to every element of type so-and-so

Tags: xslt, attributes

Can someone show me an XSL stylesheet that does this: For every element `<xref linkend="blah">` in my document, I'd like to add an additional @endterm attribute with the value `"blah.title"`.

So `<xref linkend="blah">` becomes `<xref linkend="blah" endterm="blah.title">`

where blah changes for each `<xref>`.

Template needs to also copy to the output the DOCTYPE declaration and any included ENTITY definitions at the beginning of the file, if that's possible

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stylesheet should contain an identity template rule that copies elements unchanged by default, plus a rule for `xref` elements that does

```
<xsl:template match="ref">
  <xref linkend="{@linkend}" endterm="{@linkend}.title"/>
</xsl:template>
```

XSLT does not have access to the DOCTYPE and entity definitions, so they cannot be copied. Entity references are always expanded by the XML parser before the XSLT processor gets to see them. If you want to retain them, preprocess the file to replace `&` by some other character (I tend to use `§`), and then reverse the process after the transformation.